# target panel of CollapsiblePanelExtender not visible on load, need to collapse then expand to see it

Tags: asp.net, webforms, controls

I have inherited an app that has a CollapsiblePanelExtender. The codebehind populates the control that's inside the panel when it loads. I set the CollapsiblePanelExtender to be expanded in the codebehind, but the target panel isn't visible, even though the CollapsiblePanelExtender is expanded.

If I then collapse the CollapsiblePanelExtender, and then expand it again, the panel shows up. The html is there, but it isn't showing.

Any clues would be appreciated, thanks.

```
 <div class="contentBoxTitle">
        <asp:Panel ID="expandCTL" runat="server" Width="100%">
            <asp:Image ID="expandIMG" ImageUrl="~/images/itemOpen.gif" runat="server"  />
            Client
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>

    <asp:Panel ID="profilePanel1" runat="server" >
        <div class="profileTable">
            <table width="350" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
               <tr bgcolor="ffffff">
            <th width="100" height="20" bgcolor="ffffff"><div align="right">Name:</div></th>
            <td> 
        <asp:Label ID="name" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>        </td>
          </tr>

...
(more fields here)
...
</table>
</div>
</asp:Panel>
</div>

<ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="profilePanel1" CollapsedSize ="1" ID="profilePanelCollapser"
    ExpandDirection="Vertical" ImageControlID="expandIMG" ExpandedImage="~/images/itemOpen.gif" 
    CollapsedImage="~/images/itemClosed.gif" Collapsed="false" ExpandControlID="expandCTL" CollapseControlID="expandCTL"  />
```

Comment: Is the issue only when you collapse it from codebehind? Like what happens if you just set `Collapsed="True"` and also `False`.

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan - nothing seems to happen if I set the Collapsed property. The html content of profilePanel1 is there on the client side, but the wrapping div, which is automatically created by the asp.net control has its style set to "overflow-y: hidden;" when it loads.
In the code behind, the profilePanel1.Visibility property is set to true.